# Universal Image Loader with Cardview

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I am trying to use the Universal Image Loader Project to load images in to my cardview. When I run the code below I get "ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using" error. Any help?

```
 @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final Dealviewholder  c, int i) {

     ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg",c.company_image);


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should init your ImageLoader first like this:
(In your SelfApplication onCreate Method.)

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
```